# Wrap div with first anchor in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need wrap my `.wrapMe` divs with the first link inside each of them. I have more than one box and all div has a anchor if my anchor href is `www.nnn.com` than go `www.nnn.com` when I clicked my div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    var $a = $('a', this);
  });
})
```

```css
.historyBox {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
}

.historyBox a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="historyForm">

  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="historyName">Name,Surname,Bla Bla</a>

    <span>17 news</span>
  </div>


  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD</a>

    <span>22 news</span>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- history -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Show what you want the updated structure to be.

Comment: Be clear and specific of whats your issue. No use typing this long - `I need wrap my div with first link inside my div.I need to do this how can I do that ? I thought that is a basic thing but I couldn't do.`

Comment: Ok but my post was so short but I couldn't submit stackoverflow wan to more detail too

Comment: @recruit_man: That's your indication to **provide more detail**, not to repeat yourself. That's your indication to **provide more detail**, not to repeat yourself. That's your indication to **provide more detail**, not to repeat yourself. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap all your `.wrapMe` divs inside an anchor tag.

Refer code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    $(this).wrapAll("<a href='"+ $(this).find("a").attr("href") +"' />")
  });
})
```

```css
.historyBox {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
}

.historyBox a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="historyForm">

  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="historyName">Name,Surname,Bla Bla</a>

    <span>17 news</span>
  </div>


  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD</a>

    <span>22 news</span>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- history -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need for `wrapAll`, just `wrap` when dealing with asingle element. But that will result in a `a` containing a `div` containing an `a`, which is invalid. Interactive content cannot contain interactive content.

Comment: An `a` containing a `div` containing another `a` is actually dumb (which the OP doesn't state against), thats why your comment wanting to know how the updated structure should be makes more reason.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this

```
<div class="historyBox wrapMe">
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD</a>

  <span>22 news</span>
</div>
```

to become

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">
    Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD
    <div class="historyBox wrapMe">

      <span>22 news</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

then for each `.wrapMe`, find its `a`, move that `a` to the parent, and then move the `.wrapMe` into the `a`.

```
$(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    a.appendTo(this.parentNode);
    a.append(this);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    a.appendTo(this.parentNode);
    a.append(this);
});
})
```

```css
.historyBox {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
}

.historyBox a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="historyForm">

  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="historyName">Name,Surname,Bla Bla</a>

    <span>17 news</span>
  </div>


  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD</a>

    <span>22 news</span>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- history -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That assumes that these `.wrapMe` divs are the only things in their parent, which is probably a dumb assumption on my part. So instead of `a.appendTo(this.parentNode)`, let's do `a.insertBefore(this)`:

```
$(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    a.insertBefore(this);
    a.append(this);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".wrapMe").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    a.insertBefore(this);
    a.append(this);
});
})
```

```css
.historyBox {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
}

.historyBox a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="historyForm">

  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="historyName">Name,Surname,Bla Bla</a>

    <span>17 news</span>
  </div>


  <div class="historyBox wrapMe">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="historyName">Employe ID,Employe Name,ADFHSD</a>

    <span>22 news</span>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- history -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xoLs4wbh/1/). Code Below.

```js
$('div.wrapMe').each(function() {
  var newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('wrappedUp');
  $(this).before(newDiv);
  var next = $(this).next();
  newDiv.append(this).append(next);
});
```

---

```
.wrappedUp {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid purple; 
}
```

---

```
outside
<div class="wrapMe">blah</div>
<div class="wrapMe">blah blah blah</div>
outside
<div class="wrapMe">blah blah</div>
<div class="wrapMe">blah blah</div>
outside
<div class="wrapMe">blah blah</div>
<div class="wrapMe">blah blah</div>
outside
```

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets so the example is runnable *on-site*.